# Rigify : skin overlapping clothes

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, rigify

[image]

so i know this is a weightpainting issue, but i have no confidence in my weighpainting skills, so whenever i try to fix it it just comes out worse and the deformation gets worse for some reason. can someone tell me how to fix it? .blend 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue in automatic weighting. There is no "one click solution", so I can only propose some tips to improve your weighting skills:

1 - put your subsurf modifier after (down) the armature modifier and enable two little buttons that let you see the changes you'll make in edit mode and weight painting mode.

[image]

2 - in edit mode, if you select one vertex you can read the weight assigned to every bone - vertex group in the "N" panel, vertex weight tab.
[image]

3 - in edit mode select some vertices (tipically some edge rings), then switch to weight paint mode and click the red highlited button: your weight painting will apply only to the selected vertices
[image]

4 - if you select some vertices you can directly assign a weight in the vertex properties, vertex group tab.[image]

Always consider that every vertex is moved by all the bones to which a weight is assigned.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very useful answer! In addition you may check the **Show Weights** checkbox in the *Mesh Display* panel of the *properties shelf (N)*. It'll display the weights while in *Edit Mode*.