# How to rig clothes?

Tags: rigging

I've made a guy with some clothes, I would like to rig it now, however, when I raise his leg a bit, his skin comes out more as seen here:
[image]

How do you stop this from happening?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/rigify-skin-overlapping-clothes/62831#62831. You can also delete or mask the part of the mesh which is underneath the clothes.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVfTRwXpmuQ I think, here u will find an answer

Answer (score 20):

Use the [Data Transfer Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html).

1. Select the cloth
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the rig
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to *Set parent with empty groups*
4. Select the cloth alone
5. Add the *Data Transfer* modifier (anywhere in the stack) then within the modifier:

   - Source object - Select your Rigged mesh (body)
   - Check *Vertex Data* (first in the list below Source object)
   - Select (highlight) Vertex Group(s)
   - Click *Apply*

Done. Forget about most of your nightmares and forget about destructive solutions. You may have to do some additional *weight paintings* or *shape keys with drivers* for the cloth to react the way you want with some flexion but at least, the clothes won't get through your base character as you move your rig with this method.

---

This method still works, tried in blender 3.2 with my Rig.

Comment: Just for anyone wondering: This still works in 2.8

Comment: This IS the one answer to rule them all when it comes to rigging clothing. Incredible!

Comment: Still works as of Blender 2.9
(I actually looked back because i forgot how to...Lol)

Comment: I still get a bit of clipping from this method (though on the whole it's really good). Are there any settings to fine tune to prevent this from happening? In the past I've just sculpted the clothes to cover the parts of the body that clip and are visible.

Comment: It's in fact a good starting point but to my understanding, best results will imply the use of some mesh distortion using drivers. 

At some point Cloth simulation with proper repulsion could be the way to go.

Comment: What do you select in the vertex groups option? am using Blender 3.2