# Export Mixamo Rigged Model to unity have rotation issues

Tags: unity

Im trying to export correctly some rigged models from Blender to Unity, but im facing rotation issues, that cause bones are not correctly set.

First I download the *.fbx from Mixamo, then import into Blender setting "Force Connect Childrens" and "Automatic Bone Orientation", this import the model with the bones correctly.

Now I add some clothes to the model, and add bones and bones, then I add vertex groups following this howto: [How to rig clothes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67625/how-to-rig-clothes)

Now I have correct model with the correct cloth.

The I export to FBX, using default properties (I tink I try all options here) then in Unity I drag and drop the FBX to the resources folder, and then drag and drop the model in the scene.

When I do this, using the original Mixamo fbx file, the model animate correctly, and works, but when I do this with the generated fbx from blender, the model appear deformed when I run some animations, and the cloth same, like the model "xplode" and the poligons go mad.

What I notice, is the Skinned Mesh renderere in Unity, have incorrect rotattion like show this image:
[image]

I search the origin of the rotation because the transform of the element is set correctly to 0,0,0, and I found that the rotated object is the root bone of the Mesh renderer, is rotates like -158º

I try to fix manually but this rotate the model, and all animations deform completly the model. I think all bones ans skinned mesh render have incorrect rotations, but I dont find how to fix, because in blender all appear correctly, but when I import into Unity are broken.

some idea? thanks.

Comment: Fixed! after many many MANY google and combinations I get working:
- Import > FBX > Select Mixamo FBX file
- Main: Disable all, Armatures: "automatic Bone orientation" Only
This import the model with correct orientation, then you do what you like and then to export:
- Export > FBX
- Main: Disable all, Apply S. All local, Forward: -Z Forward, Up: Y Up | Geometries: Disable All | Armatures: "Only Deform Bones", Primary: Y Axis, Second X Axis, Null, Animation All.

Now, take the generated FBX file, drop in Unity and voila! Prefab, Armature and model with 1.0 Scale anf 0,0,0 rotation!

Comment: The issue with this is because I disable the "Force Connect Children" i cant animate the modle because the bones are not joined together and I cam move it free.. need to fix that (if I put this option, the mesh wrong orientation come back)