# Export equipable armor parts for unity

Tags: modeling, bones, unity, inverse-kinematics, armory

I'm new to blender and 3D modeling, I want to export armors as parts like upper body boots, gloves, so on..
and I want to be able equip and unequip in unity game, problem is bone weights are not exporting when I exporting armor only without character, I Tried to export with character and in unity saved that armor parts as prefabs and I remove them from character, but.. when I tried to equip again that prefabs they are not working no more they are transparent, skinned mesh renderer got problems.

Can anyone explain how to do wha I want? or link some tutorials?

here is screens from blender I created different collections for character and armor parts:
[image]
[image]

result in unity:
[image]

Comment: Vertex groups are fine? Otherwise you'd have to skin the armor: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67625/how-to-rig-clothes

Comment: yes vertex groups are fine, but if I export without character its not exporting that parts when armature is disabled(character) I think I dont know :(

Comment: Do you export to FBX? Should work... You can always export and re-import to check.

Comment: yes fbx Im trying to make game in unity

Comment: armor is not following bones in unity when exported parts only(if i export with character its ok) as fbx but in blender is fine

Comment: Can not test it right now. I'd suggest try to add an armature modifer, then export *or* parent them temporarily to see whether that works.

Comment: I tried that too, I copied armature of player in armor collection and assigned that armature to armor, when I exported in unity armors came with its own bones and player also had the bones of course I tried to replace bones in armor with player bones but not working... I can send you blend file later