# Using Rigify to make an animateable hood

Tags: rigify

I'm trying to rig up a hooded vest, but I'm pretty new to using the Rigify features. I've got the bones added to the metarig in the shape I want them, using the superchain_copy as a base, but I'm not sure how to set it up to build a controller, force it to rotate only on one axis, have the middle "rib" move half as much as the front rib, etc...

I see all the nifty widgets and controllers that Rigify creates - how do I create my own for this hood? Or would it be better to break those bones off of the rig, leave that in meta-rig form, parent the hood to that, and just pose the bones "manually" as necessary? I'm not going to have the character pull the hood up and down a whole lot.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In past posts, I've noticed a lot of people directing me to old answers or tutorials. I had presumed someone's solved this, and had a ready answer. Hopefully my edit is a better fit.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67625/how-to-rig-clothes/

Comment: That's cool, but not my intention. I've got a ring of parented bones (disconnected) at the front edge of the hood, another halfway back, and a "spine" up the back. I've set the bone roll to point their Z axis backward. Doing this manually means the bottom bones in the loop rotate, but as I move up the ring, they have to both rotate and move as the hood stretches to clear the character's head. It also means the middle loop has to move in the same manner, but about half as much rotation as the front loop. The bones in the spine need to get closer together as the hood folds up behind the head.