# Weight painting problems

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have a problem with weight painting in blender. As you may already know, automatic weights while rigging is not at its wisest most of the times... Is there any way of making my struggles with animating this human better?

When I move right arm his palm won't move, and some other issues occur as well... I don't know how else can I help myself...

Any advice from the "wiser ones" would be appreciated :)

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: You can upload a blend [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/rigify-skin-overlapping-clothes/62831#62831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your mesh, in the modifier stack delete the armature modifier, apply the mirror, parent the object to the armature with automatic weights and put the suburf modifier after the Armature modifier (down). You'll have a good starting point to tweak with the tricks described in my comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir... I think I can work with this!!!