# Leg going through clothing

Tags: rigging

Hi I have a simple model of a person and rigged it to make a walking animation. However, if I pose the skeleton, the legs stick out of the clothing as shown below: [image]

I've tried messing with the weightings so that the clothing vertices respond more to the bone and the leg less so but this didn't work. Do I need to create more bones for parts of clothing or is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks

Comment: did you check that only one bone has a weight of 1 on the legs clothing. Probably there is somewhere an unmoved bone which will try to keep the clothing at its original position

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62818/rigify-skin-overlapping-clothes/62831#62831

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that any vertex of the cloth close to a vertex of the leg should have the same weights relatively to ALL bones involved (not only relatively to the closer bone, the upper leg in your example). This can be accomplieshed with weight painting tecniques, or using the vertex weight tab in the "N" properties panel (with a mesh in edit mode and a vertex weighted selected): you can select some vertices of the cloth, a close vertex of the leg (last selected is named active "active") and press the "file and arrow" icon: this will transfer all weights from active to selected vertices.

[image]

Comment: So I need to add weight to the piece of clothing for the upper and leg bones as well as the foot bones?

Comment: Generally that zone of the body is influenced mainly by upper leg and hips. Select a body vertex in that zone with a movement you like and "read" and copy its values.

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using a mask modifier.
You can mask the areas of the legs that are under the clothes, therefore they won't stick out when you move the legs.